# Fluent Nhibernate - HQL select problem

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hql

I am new to NHibernate. 
I am using Fluent Nhibernate and when I run a simple query I get null results.
Here is my configuration:

Fluent Configuration:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                            .ShowSql() 
                            .ConnectionString(c => c
                                   .FromConnectionStringWithKey("MY_DB")))
                        .Mappings(m =>m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CsrDAL.Mappings.CsrRegistrationMap>())  
                        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Entity Class

```
 public class Industry
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CsrRegistration> ReferencedRegistrations { get; set; }
}
```

Map Class

```
public class IndustryMap : ClassMap<Industry>
{
    public IndustryMap()
    {
        Table("industries");

        Id(x => x.Id. "id");
        Map(x => x.Name, "name");
    }
 }
```

Repository Fetch Method

```
 public static IList<Industry> getData(CsrRegistration registration)
   {
       using (var session = CsrDalHelper.OpenSession())
       {
           using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
           {
               try
               {
                   IQuery q = session.CreateQuery("from Industry ind where ind.Id=1");
                   IList<Industry> inds = 
                       q.List<Industry>();
                   return inds;  // <-- This is null
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!
Dimitris

Comment: Do you have records in you industries table?

Comment: remove the try and post the exception (if there is one)

Comment: Also why are you return a list for a single item, i.e. you are returning a list for a unique item in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in session management, somewhere else in my code.

I was wrongly adding collection items to an entity outside the NH session.

As a newcomer to nhibernate, I am now studying the docs in more details.

Thank you